# Read the pixel value of SKTexture

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

How can I get the color value of a SKSpriteNode or SKTexture at a pixel offset?

```
let atlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "SomeAtlas")
let texture = atlas.textureNamed("SomeTexture")
let node = SKSpriteNode(texture: texture)

// Something like this...    
let pixel: SKColor = node.pixelAtPoint(x: 30, y: 100)
```

If I were writing direct OpenGL I'd just load my texture into a framebuffer and use `glReadPixels`, but I can't seem to get that sort of low-level access in SpriteKit...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can read anything from the texture directly, but if you load the image as a UIImage first then you can read pixel values from that and also use it to create your sprite's textures. You could wrap it up in a subclass too to make things nicer.